# Native SQL query producing different results than same SQL query in SQL Workbench

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Native SQL query producing different results than same SQL query in SQL Workbench

I have this SQL query

```
Select distinct ce.external_id, ce.isid, ji.name, ji.controlled_status, ji.jurisdiction_name, ji.result_comments,
ji.code_name, s.corporate_id
from cs_jurisdiction_information ji
Join substance s on ji.substance_id = s.id
Join controlled_event ce on ce.id = s.controlled_event_id 
and ce.calling_system_id = 402 and ji.controlled_status = 'CONTROLLED' 
and ce.external_id = 'someExperimentID'
```

However the same query within my Spring boot application produces the correct number of results, but it is duplicating the first record for all records returned rather than the corresponding data.

[image]

Here is my Repository:

```
package com.pdb.testdbconn.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.pdb.testdbconn.dto.ExperimentDetails;

public interface ExperimentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<ExperimentDetails, String> {

    @Query(value = "Select ce.external_id, ce.isid, ji.name, ji.controlled_status, " +
    "ji.jurisdiction_name, ji.result_comments," +
    "ji.code_name, s.corporate_id " +
    "from cs_jurisdiction_information ji " +
    "Join substance s on ji.substance_id = s.id " +
    "Join controlled_event ce on ce.id = s.controlled_event_id " +
    "and ce.calling_system_id = 402 and ji.controlled_status = 'CONTROLLED' " +
    "and ce.external_id = :externalId", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ExperimentDetails> getExperimentDetails(@Param("externalId") String externalId);
}
```

And here is my POJO, ideally I did not want to be using @Entity annotation here, but that is part of another question on stackoverflow which I am still working on:

```
package com.pdb.testdbconn.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class ExperimentDetails {
    @Id
    private String externalId;
    private String isid;
    private String name;
    private String controlledStatus;
    private String jurisdictionName;
    private String resultComments;
    private String codeName;
    private String corporateId;
}
```

Why is the first record returned being duplicated in the rest of the result?

Answer (score 0):

The first query uses DISTINCT, the query in your Repository does not.  My guess is that the Join statements are causing the extra results.  Try removing the DISTINCT from your first query to see if it looks like the results you're seeing in your Repository.

Comment: I've tried both, distinct has no affect the records returned will be the same in either case, only that in Spring the record 1 data shows up for all 4 records

Comment: Is "ce.external_id = :externalId"   and "ce.external_id = 'someExperimentID'" the same conditions?